# Student Position ranking in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a project on student ranking. The sample school does three terminal exam in a year. I created three different tables for each terminal exam, (i.e. firstermsar for first, secondtermsar for second, thirdtermsar for third term respectively).

#### Table structure is like this:

```
id   studentid   matca1   matca2   matexam   engca1   engca2    engexam
1       2          15       14        40       12       10         60
2       1          10       5         56       9        13         35
3       4          11       9         45       14       17         40
4       5          14       1         50       20       0          60
```

Students with id 4 and 5 are in class1 while students 2 and 1 are in in class2. I have a seperate table for classes and also seperate table for student profile info.

Now, I already output the result slip but without ranks which looks like this

```
StudentId: 2     Full Name: Fawaz James     Class: Pry 2     Overall Position: -

                        1stAss    2ndAss    ExamScore    Grade    Position   Rmks
Mark Obtainable           20       20          60         
English                   12       10          60          A         -       Excellent
Mathematics               15       14          40          B         -       V. Good
```

Though am a starter, and my code is a mess, its provided underneath. Moreover I need help with calculating the overall position on class basis and subject position on class basis. Please help me as my project depends on this for approval and am in my deadline week before I got introduced to stack Overflow.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM firsttermsars
WHERE studentID=$stuID AND year=\"$_SESSION[year]\""; #27
$result = mysql_query($query)
or die ("Couldn't execute query.");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "<h2> First Term Stint Report Sheet for $namet during the SESSION $year</h2>";
echo "<table class='table1'>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td></td>";
echo "<td><b>1st Assessment</b></td><td><b>2nd Assessment</b></td>
<td><b>Mid Term<br />Exam</b></td><td><b>Mid Term<br />Total Score</b></td><td><b>Grade<br />Point</b></td></tr>";
echo "<tr> <td><b>Mark Obtainable</b></td><td><b>30</b></td><td><b>20</b></td><td><b>50</b></td><td><b>100</b></td><td><b>||=||</b></td></tr><tr>";

$tetal = $row['thirdengtest']+$row['thirdengexam']+$row['eng1'];
if ($tetal >="1") {
$q2 = "1";
$sq2 = "100";
echo "<td>English Language: </td>";
echo "<td>{$row['eng1']}</td><td>{$row['thirdengtest']}</td><td>{$row['thirdengexam']}</td> <td>";
$total1 = $row['thirdengtest']+$row['thirdengexam']+$row['eng1'];
echo $total1."</td><td>";

if ($total1>="75")
echo "A1";
elseif ($total1>="70")
echo "B2";
elseif ($total1>="65")
echo "B3"; 
elseif ($total1>="60")
echo "C4";
elseif ($total1>="55")
echo "C5";
elseif ($total1>="50")
echo "C6";
elseif ($total1>="45")
echo "D7";
elseif ($total1>="40")
echo "E8";
elseif ($total1>="1")
echo "F9"; 
elseif ($total1=="0")
echo "-";
else
echo "F";
echo "</td></tr>";
}

$tetal = $row['thirdmathtest']+$row['thirdmathexam']+$row['math1'];
if ($tetal >="1") {
$q3 = "1";
$sq3 = "100";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Mathematics </td>";
echo "<td>{$row['math1']}</td><td>{$row['thirdmathtest']}</td> <td>{$row['thirdmathexam']}</td> <td>";
$total2 = $row['thirdmathtest']+$row['thirdmathexam']+$row['math1'];
echo $total2."</td><td>";

if ($total2>="75") echo "A1"; elseif ($total2>="70") echo "B2"; elseif ($total2>="65") echo "B3"; elseif ($total2>="60") echo "C4"; elseif ($total2>="55") echo "C5"; elseif ($total2>="50") echo "C6"; elseif ($total2>="45") echo "D7"; elseif ($total2>="40") echo "E8"; elseif ($total2>="1") echo "F9"; elseif ($total2=="0") echo "-"; else echo "F";
echo "</td></tr>";
}

?>
```

I hope you can help me like this, and hope is not complicated. I wanted to add the picture of the output but its complaining i don't have the required reputation

Comment: Could you edit the code down to just the part that's relevant to the question?

Comment: First *normalize* your data! A DBMS table is NOT a spreadsheet!

Comment: how do i normalize the data, is it at the entry level into the database or using php. I do not really get it please

Comment: Normalization is a fundamental concept of databases, and (in that context) easily 'googleable'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, in the database, make a new column for total('Total') and ('Grade'), and when you are submitting the marks details to your database, add the marks and grade and then submit the total to the database, instead of calculating them while retrieving the information.

Second, when you are selecting students from the database, use the SQL command:

```
SELECT * FROM firsttermsars ORDER BY Total DESC
```

[More info on ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

This will automatically return the list of students in descending order of their total marks.
Similarly, for subject ranking, you can have a separate table, where ranking is done on subject marks

Then, while retrieving the data,

```
<table>
<?php
    while ($i<$num) //num is number of rows
    {
?>
<tr><td><?php echo mysql_result($result,$i,"Name"); ?></td>
//... Similarly for all clumns
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

This should make the table with all students ranked according to their total marks. Similarly you can make a table for ranking by subject marks.

This is how i would solve the problem. Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks, TheScarecrow to be sincere I don't really get what you saying

Comment: I'm just saying that instead of ranking the results after getting the data from the database, you could simply get the data ranked already...

Answer (score 0):

Although i am late, but it may help some one.
First of All you should calculate Obtained marks and store in database table.
For simplicity i am showing just 3 column.

```
Id  Name    Obtained
1   A       100
2   B       58
3   L       88
4   F       102
5   C       99
```

Insert the row in table , then run this query to get Position of student.

```
SELECT id, name, Obtained, FIND_IN_SET( score, (    
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( score
ORDER BY score DESC ) 
FROM scores )
) AS position
FROM scores
WHERE id = 5
```

Detail here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table